# Does the closest point on an analytic manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ change analytically as $x$ does?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, analyticity, real-algebraic-geometry

Given an analytic manifold $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, analytically diffeomorphic to the closed hypercube $[-1,1]^{dim(M)}$, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ close enough to $M$ there is a unique $x_0=\text{arg}\min_{y\in M}d(x,y)$. If $x_0$ is an interior point of $M$ and we change $x$ analytically does $x_0$ change analytically also? More formally, if $x(t)$ is a real analytic path in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $x(0)=x$ is the corresponding $x_0(t)$ analytic in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a neighhbourhood of $t=0$? Is there a situation where $x_0$ changes analytically in the manifold but not if we view the manifold as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

My work so far has been based around the Implicit Function Theorem, but it hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Comment: The closed hyper cube itself isn't an analytic sub-manifold of its ambient Euclidean space, but if it were: consider the points $(t,1+\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $t\geq 0$ the parameter, $\varepsilon >0$ small and fixed. It's analytic in $t$, the distance to the cube is constant near $t=0$, but eventually non-constant and I suppose not analytic in $t=1$.

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to stipulate that $x_0$ would have to be an interior point of the manifold, as it's definitely not analytic in at least some situations on the boundary. Edited now.

Comment: I was confused, sorry. Maybe I still am: how can $x_0$ possibly be in the interior?

Comment: How can the _closest point to $x$_ be an _interior point_ of the manifold (unless $x$ is itself in the interior, in which case $x_0=x$)?

Comment: Perhaps you meant that $x$ must be an interior point of the region of $\mathbb R^n$ where there is a _unique_ closest point in $M$?

Comment: I mean that $x_0\in M$ is an interior point of $M$, not $x$ which can be anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, although close enough to $M$ so that $x_0$ is unique. As an example take $M$ to be the unit hemisphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$, $x_3\geq 0$, which I believe is analytically diffeomorphic to $[-1,1]^2$. $x_0$ is in the interior of $M$ if and only if the corresponding $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies $x_3>0$, in which case $x_0=\frac{x}{|x|}$ and so is an analytic function of $x$.